# What is the easiest way to create a local variable with the same type as a deduced argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, auto, template-argument-deduction

Namely:

```
[](auto const& foo) {
    ??? bar; // should be same base type as foo, minus const&
}
```

So far, I'm using:

```
typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(foo)>::type>::type combination
```

But I'm really hoping theres an easier alternative!

Comment: As far as I've read, I was `auto` type deduction semantics, but in a place where I need to use `decltype` since I'm not assigning an expression.  They introduced `decltype(auto) foo = bar` for the reverse problem, but now I want `decltype<auto>(bar) foo;` ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::decay<decltype(whatever)>::type`, or `decay_t` if your `std` library has been updated with it.

It emulates various kinds of function argument decays.  It handles if your arg was a reference-to-function.  On reference-to-array, it produces a pointer as well, which is less ideal.

If you want to handle those differently, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Brilliant!  Yes, it has support for `std::decay_t` so even better.